# How do I extract data from a 3rd party api and display it on my page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I need to be able to fetch invoice data from this api: https://apidoc.qoyod.com/

and display it on my page through javascript. First, the user enters an api key and then the page displays the invoice index and details.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
function displayData()
{

 const div = document.getElementById("result");


 const URL = 'https://www.qoyod.com/api/2.0/invoices/1';

   
   fetch(URL)
   
   .then((resp) => resp.json())
  
   .then(function(data)
   {
    let invoices = data.results;
    invoices.map(function(invoice){
     let p = document.createElement('p');
     p.innerHTML=`${invoice.index}`;
     
     div.appendChild(p);     
    })   
   })
 
  
  
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(json.stringify(error));
  })
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Qoyod Assignment</title>

  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="root">
  
<input style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter API Key" />
<button onClick="displayData();" >Display Data</button>
<div id="result"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

The challenge here is the "fetch" part. I am sure there is something I am missing out on while extracting the data. Maybe I'm not using the API URL correctly? I just can't seem to be able to "grab" the API data into my"data" object. When I click the button, I get no output at all!

Also, I need to figure out how to use the entered api key to fetch the data. I honestly have no clue at all. It's my first time to work with apis and I feel sooo lost :((

If there are any API pros out there, I would greatly appreciate your assistance!

Thanks

UPDATE: I managed to add the api as a header while fetching the data in this format:

```js
fetch(URL, {
  headers: new Headers({
    'API-KEY' : '[api-key-here]' })
})
```

However, I got this error in my browser: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.qoyod.com/api/2.0/invoices/1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)."

Does this mean I need to be granted access by the owner of the api server?

Comment: `json.stringify` Capitalization often matters in programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to put your API-KEY in the frontend of your website. You should have a backend where you request from the API in the backend and then render the data in your frontend. You are facing Cross-Origin issues because you are requesting from a different URL than the one you already used to load the frontend. This is a security measure in many APIs endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below code snippet. and make sure you have data in correct `JSON Object` format. Below i try to replicate the problem. assume you have data in `data`  variable after Ajax call.

```js
function displayData() {
  const div = document.getElementById("result");

  /* const URL = 'https://www.qoyod.com/api/2.0/invoices/1';

     fetch(URL)
     
     .then((resp) => resp.json())
    
     .then(function(data)
     { */

  let data = {
    results: [{
        "index": 1,
        "code": "170"
      },
      {
        "index": 2,
        "code": "175"
      }
    ]
  };

  let invoices = data.results;
  invoices.map(function(invoice) {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = `${invoice.index}`;

    div.appendChild(p);
  })
  // })
  /*
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(json.stringify(error));
  })*/
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Qoyod Assignment</title>

  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="root">

    <input style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter API Key" />
    <button onClick="displayData();">Display Data</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! the code you gave me produced the following output: 1 2

Comment: But, how do i get it to fetch the actual data from the api?

Comment: i thought you are getting data from API successfully and have issue in render into `result` div.

Comment: Oh no my challenge is to EXTRACT the data from the API after the user entering the API key

Comment: what the error you are getting for fetching data exactly ?

Comment: I am just not getting any data on the screen. When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: I really hope you can help me write the correct code that will extract the data I need from the api: https://apidoc.qoyod.com... Thanks

Comment: whats the issue in `fetch` for api? have you tried in `postman` ?

Comment: No I don't know how to use postman, and I currently have limited time to finish this assignment, so can't learn a new program.. I am just using plain JavaScript to do this.

Comment: its a simple software and plugin to test your api. just add into your chrome browser to test `postman` https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Anyhow, the last error I was getting on chrome was this: "OPTIONS https://www.qoyod.com/api/2.0/invoices/1 404
displayData @ scripts.js:9
onclick @ (index):21
(index):1 Failed to load https://www.qoyod.com/api/2.0/invoices/1: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch", and when I shared it with the api owner they said: "our servers do not reply to OPTIONS requests and that is unchangeable". Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: and btw I just downloaded the postman plugin on chrome, and retested the api connection on chrome but it still failed.. Is there some kind of configuration I need to do to make my application work with postman?

Answer (score -1):

If you are use postman than its very easy to you. You need api key pass to header and they already provide what data pass in body.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I use the "fetch" statement instead of xmlhttprequest?

Comment: @maha yes you can use.

Comment: I was able to attach the header to the fetch request. But, now I am getting this error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.qoyod.com/api/2.0/invoices/1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).".. How can i solve this issue? (FYI I am not using postman)